# Jquery Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery

What is the correct way to get a response from a PHP when I do an ajax request using Jquery?

I have this code for Jquery:

```
$('#quote-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dateType: 'json',
        url: 'mail.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

And PHP code `mail.php`:

```
// Some mail functions here

$mailSent = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
$return['msg'] = $mailSent ? 'mail sent' : 'mail failure';  
echo json_encode($return);
```

I tried to alert the reponse `alert(data.msg)` but it's saying undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at whatever developer tools are available to you to see the request that is being returned. If you get to the `alert` then the request is coming back fine. You just need to inspect what `data` looks like (do a console.log(data) in Chrome to view it)

Comment: Could you try to alert(data)? :)

Comment: You need to parse your JSON after success with [`.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or try to use [`.getJSOn()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `.ajax()`

Comment: I've check on the response tab and it states: `(an empty string)`

Comment: @JMax - you don't have to use either of that. All you need is to specify `dataType: 'json'` and he typed `dateType`.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from other things that I haven't tested, but I just saw that there's a misspell in your ajax options:

```
dateType: 'json'
```

Change it to:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: That should do it ^_^ Just got there before I did xD

Comment: Keener eyes than I have this morning! :)

Comment: Wow I did not see that. Thanks! Though there's another problem. It's now saying that `data` is null.

Comment: Use your browsers' console and check what's the raw response you get. If the response doesn't look like JSON but contains a warning or something else coming from PHP - you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting your headers to return JSON?
This way jQuery knows you're returning JSON

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: dude I don't think it has a need

Answer (score 0):

First change the spelling of `datatype` as mentioned by Kavousi. Then parse your incoming data some thing like this in your response

```
  var response = obj = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(response.msg);
```